# Working with hybrid auth and codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, hybridauth

I am trying to build a project using CodeIgniter and for sign up purposes, I am using Hybrid Auth library. I am using a link similar to "http://localhost/project/hauth/endpoint?hauth.done=Google" as my redirect URI for facebook and google.

app is working fine with it. But the problem is I can't understand what this "hauth.done" means.
As soon as I allow the permission, it redirects me to the above provided link where I don't know how to receive data/userprofile information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is updated library which works with the latest HybridAuth (v2.10) and CodeIgniter (v3.x)

https://github.com/ApacheEx/CodeIgniter-HybridAuth

`hauth.done` uses for finishing authorization via `Hybrid_Endpoint::process();` which calls `processAuthDone` to save all needed tokens for later API requests.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you should provide proper redirect URL when call an api and after that when Hauth redirect to your desire page you can retrieve your information according to your code reference.
Otherwise as you are using Codeigniter, in my advice use git reference where you can find complete code for your application directory. In that code they already getting user profile info.
[Git repo](https://github.com/andacata/HybridIgniter)